# Unable to validate magento custom login form in fancybox

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

I am trying to validate the following form in fancybox popup but it keeps on submitting the form instead of doing the validation what am I doing wrong in this? This works perfectly when Outside fancybox.

```
<form id="login-form-popup" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost') ?>">
                 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
                 <li>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Email ID</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Email ID') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" name="login[username]" id="email" title="Email Address" />
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" name="login[password]" id="pass" title="Password" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="buttonstyle" type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="subloginpop" id="subloginpop" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><div class="input-box">
                     <a class="forgot-password" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>">Forgot Your Password?</a></div>
                </li>
                </form>
<script  type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
 var theLoginFormpop = new VarienForm('login-form-popup', true);
//]]> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout below link to validate any form with magento. Magento generally uses class names to validate form. All validation classes are written inside validate.js file.

[Check this link to know more.](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Comment: It does work when I am not in fancybox so I am sure I dont have any class names incorrect

Comment: Can you see any javascript errors in firebug.

Comment: none. just it never goes to the validation class I have written in script tag above. It is working on other phtml page just not in fancybox

Comment: You can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZMEEW/, it may help you.

Comment: I want to use Varien form validation not custom I have a registration form also.